# Grouped list and sub items group in flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

[Image result now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QdZqy.png)
I have created a main list of items now i need a sub list items group also, but when i want to create sub list items group then it appears that without height i cant place them and when i set height then this is just a scrollable containter thats the problem. Can any one help me.
Thanks in advance.

```
  List<Reply> replyList = [];

  // sub Items
  buildItemItem(List<Reply> reply){

    return Container(
      height: 65,
      margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 30),
      child: ListView.builder(

        itemCount: reply.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 40, top: 8, right: 10, bottom: 8),
            child: Row(
              children: [
                Container(
                  height: 40,
                  width: 40,
                  child: CircleAvatar(
                    backgroundImage: NetworkImage(reply[index].photo),
                  ),
                ),
                Expanded(
                  flex: 4,
                  child: Container(
                    margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10),
                    child: Column(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: [
                        Text('${reply[index].name}',
                          style: TextStyle(
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                              fontSize: 12
                          ),),
                        Text('${reply[index].Item}'),
                        Text('${reply[index].createdAt}',
                          style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 10,
                              color: Colors.grey
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                
            ),

          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }



  // main Item list
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 15, top: 8, right: 10, bottom: 8),
          child: Row(
            children: [
              Container(
                height: 40,
                width: 40,
                child: CircleAvatar(
                  backgroundImage: NetworkImage(photo),
                ),
              ),
              Expanded(
                flex: 4,
                child: Container(
                  margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10),
                  child: Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: [
                      Text('$name',
                        style: TextStyle(
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            fontSize: 12
                        ),),
                      Text('$Item'),
                      Text('$createdAt',
                        style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 10,
                            color: Colors.grey
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
        
            ],
          ),

        ),
        FutureBuilder(
          future: getReply(id),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            return snapshot.data !=null ?  buildItemItem(snapshot.data) : circularProgress();
          },
        ),
        Divider(height: 0.0,),
      ],
    );


  }

}
```

Comment: Do you want to have something like a tree view?

Comment: Yes , you are right.

Comment: If you want i can share you full code

Comment: Yeah please append it in Question.